# html- page doesnt scroll fully once spoiler is open

Tags: html

http://vendettatransportation.com/ThingsToDo.html

the issue is on that page, when you click the restaurants spoiler it causes the spoiler to open, problem is once its open the page doesnt allow you to scroll threw the whole page, like the scroll amount it not adjusted to the size.

so i guess what im asking is what did i do wrong? or more specifically did i miss to add something,

ill be looking threw my code again, i think its a div tag issue. but would like assistance incase i need a line of code i don't know of.

```
<span>
<!--Visible Content-->
<div align="Left" class="TTDButtonLink"><a type="button" title="Click to show/hide content" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}" style="color: #FF0004">
    Restaurants
</a></div>

<div id="spoiler" style="display:none" align="Left"> Restaurant Image: Content </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></div>
```

Comment: Post your codes in your question.

Comment: updated with the spoiler code, but i think its the div tag as stated, which has a couple hundred lines... i think its the div tag because it seems anytime the page adjust(image loads up, spoiler spreads open, etc) it has the issue of not displaying the full content

Comment: i assume a fix for this could be setting a div tag containing everything in side the html tag and set its overflow to scroll. but would like to know why this is happening either way

Comment: *scratch that* that didnt work either :(

Comment: You can leave some padding bottom in your scrolling contents (Hint: you can diagnose your content size via Developer Console)

Comment: @Raptor i dont think you know the issue that i mean. on the link provide, if you click the Restaurants link it opens a spoiler(code provided) if your fully scrolled down(of the entire page) the div adjusts to the new now visible content, but it moves the content farther down, causing it to go off screen, the problem with that is you can NOT scroll farther, its like it does not recognize the readjustment of content.